# JPA Eclipselink: How to find which relationship is causing error

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I get the following error when attempting to persist an object:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException:  During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST`

Is there any simple way to tell which relationship has the problem object?

It is possible that the persisted object has many relationships and a trial and error or find by elimination works, but I would like to know if there is a simpler quicker way to identify the problem relationship object.

Update:  I encounter this problem periodically, and I have always been able to find the source of the problem, or have been able to reorder the operations in order to solve the problem, but my issue is the amount of time that it takes to find the offending object.

My solutions have always been found by trial and error.  I sometimes find the solution in minutes, but sometimes it takes hours.  My question is: is there an easier way to find which of possibly many relationships is causing the problem.  The exception only claims that a "new object" was found through a "relationship", this does not help me to find which object or which relationship.  Is there a log or a way to tell the system to provide a more specific error?

Comment: Maybe you want to see http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/eclipselink-users/msg00553.html If possible, show your code. I can not guess what is happening unless you provide more info.

Comment: Arthur:  Thank you and I appreciate your response, but my question is more general than that.  I have updated my question to give you a better idea as to what I'm looking for.

Comment: Have you tried to configure the eclipselink.logging.level in persistence.xml - http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging??

Comment: The error message should include the object that caused the error, does it not?

Comment: It shows the main object, but it does not show which related object is causing the problem.

Comment: Log a bug to have the related object added to the exception.  You could also put a breakpoint in the exception.

Answer (score 1):

The next is a listener for all the request of your APP, to activate it :

1. In your `persistence.xml` add:

   ```
   <property name="eclipselink.session.customizer" value="dz.bilelovitch.QueryListener"/>
   ```
2. Create the `QueryListener`:

   ```
   import org.eclipse.persistence.config.SessionCustomizer; 
   import org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Session;

   public class QueryListener implements SessionCustomizer {

       @Override
       public void customize(Session aSession) throws Exception {
           System.out.println("log " + aSession.getLog() );
       }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
```

will cause EclipseLink to show more detailed logs which can help you to detect the reason of error more closely.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Tried it, it still doesn't give the detail I need.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is simple: debugging and testing. JUnit/TestNG and debugging mode should be your friends. There's nothing special with this error.

Moreover, Cascade.PERSIST may be missing, therefore you get that exception.
More info: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Cascading